# Python kivy Problems with rewriting python in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have some problems with rewriting python code in kivy format

Here is the class "Settings" which has method to change screen.

```
class SettingsMenu(Screen):
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if touch.button == 'right':
        self.parent.transition.direction = "right"
        self.parent.transition.duration = 0.6
        self.parent.current = "MainMenu"
```

And I want to rewrite it in kivy this way (or something like that):

```
<SettingsMenu>
name: "SettingsMenu"
on_touch_down:
    if button == "right":
        root.parent.transition.direction = "right"
        root.parent.transition.duration = 0.6
        root.parent.current = "MainMenu"
```

How should I do it correctly?

(Edit) Here is the full code. I just create two screens and when we are on SettingsMenu screen, I want to switch back to MainMenu screen with *right mouse button*

(Commented on_touch_down in SettingsMenu python class works correctly, but when I try to make it in kivy way, I switch the screen with any mouse button, but desired was *right mouse button*)

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')


class MainMenu(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsMenu(Screen):
    pass
    # def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    #     if touch.button == 'right':
    #         self.parent.transition.direction = "right"
    #         self.parent.transition.duration = 0.6
    #         self.parent.current = "MainMenu"


class MenuManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


main_kv = Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class THEApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return main_kv


THEApp().run()
```

This is the Kivy file (indentation may be broken during copy-paste, but I had no problems with syntax):

```
MenuManager:
   MainMenu:
   SettingsMenu:

<MainMenu>
    name: "MainMenu"
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
    Button:
        text: "Button 1 on Main Menu Screen"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.transition.duration = 0.6
            root.manager.current = "SettingsMenu"
<SettingsMenu>
    name: "SettingsMenu"
    button: "right"
    on_touch_down:
        if root.button == "right": \
        root.parent.transition.direction = "right"; \
        root.parent.transition.duration = 0.6; \
        root.parent.current = "MainMenu"
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: "Label 1 on SettingsMenu"
```

Comment: Please consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do python code/logic for an `on_touch_down:` attribute in a `kv` file, but it is a bit goofy. I think your `kv` file will work like this:

```
<SettingsMenu>
    name: "SettingsMenu"
    on_touch_down:
        if args[1].button == "right": \
        root.parent.transition.direction = "right"; \
        root.parent.transition.duration = 0.6; \
        root.parent.current = "MainMenu"
```

In the `kivy` language, you can access the `args` of an `on_<action>` method (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)). So the code above checks the `button` attribute of the `touch` arg.

Note that the `if` statement in the `kv` file must be on a single line. That is the reason for the `\` characters (to escape endlines) and the `;` (to delimit the lines of code).

Comment: Your kivy suggestion works but initially I tried to change the screen by pressing the **right mouse button** (see my python class), but with your example, the screen changes on pressing any mouse button, not just the right one. Could you suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Not without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the post, so you can check out the reproducible example

Comment: See updated answer.